# How to create dynamic tabs in React Navigation v3

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, expo

I have stack navigator wrapped with app container:

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
  },
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Home should have dynamic tabs. I want to load some info from backend and then generate tabs.

And here is my **Home** component:

```
class Home extends Component {
  get tabs() {
    return {
      Main: { screen: Demo },
      World: { screen: Demo },
    };
  }

  get tabOptions() {
    return {
      // options...
    };
  }

  render() {
    const Tabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(this.tabs, this.tabOptions);
    return <Tabs />;
  }
}
```

In this case I am getting this error:

[image: error 1]

But if I am wrapping with createAppContainer...

```
const Tabs = createAppContainer(createMaterialTopTabNavigator(this.tabs, this.tabOptions));
```

...then I am getting warning about more than one container in app.

[image: warning]

So how to make dynamic tabs in a right way?

---

**UPD 1.**  Real code of getting tabs which I use now with yellow warning.

```
get tabs() {
  const { categories } = this.props;
  return reduce((acc, item) => assoc(prop('name', item), Demo, acc), {})(categories); // ramda
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That error shows up because wrapping a navigator as a component is antipattern since the navigation prop is being broken that way.

instead, don't use a class , use plain functions, or you are gonna struggle so much like the other guys that tried to use a component

```
function tabs(){
   return {
      Main: { screen: Demo },
      World: { screen: Demo },
    }
  }

  function tabOptions(){
    return {
      // options...
    };
  }

  export default createMaterialTopTabNavigator(tabs(), tabOptions())
```

Comment: But how I will use redux inside to generate tabs (tabs() function in your  example).  I've hardcoded them just for example. In real it will transform array of objects to react-navigation-friendly object.

Comment: ;-; i'm kinda noob at redux, if i understand it correctly it's used for storage. However, they are gonna drop support for it in the next release of react navigation so i would suggest not to depend on it.

Comment: Oh , and for your approach, you can workaround using a component navigator this way https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html   , you just replace the line `const Tabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(this.tabs, this.tabOptions);` with `const Tabs = withNavigation(createMaterialTopTabNavigator(this.tabs, this.tabOptions));
` , however there has been some times when withnavigation didn't worked for me

Comment: I think my choice is take react-native-tab-view and create with it, because react navigation can't handle it.

Comment: yeah, react navigation is not designed to be dynamic, it's super static, wich can have his benefits and problems